# Confidence interval

Tags: statistics

**I have this statement:**

> If a 95% confidence interval for the mean was computed as (25,50),
>   then if several more samples were taken with the same sample size,
>   then 95% of them would have a sample mean between (25,50)

**And I know this statement is false, but I want to know exactly why.**

**My thought:**

> If several more samples were taken with the same sample size, and
>   created a confidence interval from each statistic, over the long run
>   95% confidence interval; (25,50) will contain the true population
>   parameter (should I say true population mean?), not a sample mean.
>
> For example, if we take 100 different samples and compute 95%
>   confidence interval for each sample, then approximately 95 of the 100
>   confidence intervals will contain the true mean value.

Any better idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is false because of the part of the sentence that said " $95\text{%}$ of them would have the mean between $(25,50)$". The true statement should be "...$95\text{%}$ of them would contain the true population mean $\mu$. It could be that none of the sample mean is between $25$ and $50$ but the confident interval still contains $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is my thought a bit away from what you wrote?

Comment: May I ask which part is wrong? Actually, the first box is the false statement and the second box is my whole thought.

Comment: Because I use "true population parameter" instead of "true population mean"?

Comment: No. The wrong part is the $(25,50)$ interval. The C.I invertal can vary for each sample.

Comment: Oh I understand what you meant. Thanks!